# LyX: How to put more than one characters in single bra or ket?

Tags: lyx, physics

I am a new user of LyX and want to write a ket vector with an entry having a subscript or with two entries. I have mentioned the `\usepackage{braket}` in the LaTeX preamble and am able to use ket vectors with a single argument.

1. When I write `\Ket0`, the output is |0>. When I write `\Ket00`, it gives |0>0. If I try `\Ket{00}`, it gives |{>00}. I tried all the different brackets also.
2. When I want to use subscripts with the entry, the ket in output file includes only the first entry and the subscript is shown outside the ket. I have tried using {} around the complete expression here too.

I can do what I want in TeX mode using ctrl + L but I wish to do it the LyX way.

Comment: Put the argument in braces \Ket{00}. Without braces the argument is the next character.

Comment: There are not LyX way for unknown macros other that Ctri+L or mess with layouts and modules (Help> Customization) that is a task enough complex and time-consuming to think twice if Ctrl+L is so bad.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I already tried that still, the argument was the first character in braces.

Comment: @Fran thanks for the clarification.